# JavaScript predefined variable "name"

Tags: javascript, variables

I am learning JavaScript and just discovered that variable named **name**, actually is predefined, sitting in global context.

[image]

I created new, completely clear html file (have not even written any html in it). Also I tested it in chrome, opera and firefox, same...

I wonder why is that, beyond my curiosity, there was case when that variable was assigned to value **"string"**, by itself, have not even touched it. Why is that there? what is it doing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: Please have a look at documentations or google that. "js window.name" returns many answers to your question

Comment: It is not **Javascript** (which is a programming language) that has a predefined variable. You are referring to the [window object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) and should modify the title of the question as such!

Comment: also do a search for *"javascript reserved words"*

Comment: thanks, i was searching for wrong keywords as i didn't know what i was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is one of the predefined property of the global object `window`.

Since Stephan Bijzitter wants an answer with more details, here it is.

[Section 7.3.1](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name) of the current living HTML standards states that `window.name` is a property of the global object `window` that returns the name of the window and can be set, to change the name.

> The name attribute of the Window object must, on getting, return the current name of the browsing context; and, on setting, set the name of the browsing context to the new value.
>
> The name gets reset when the browsing context is navigated to another origin.

Comment: 46k score and an answer that is worse than a link-only comment.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Did you expect me to quote a part of the HTML5 specification for this question?

Comment: I would expect everyone to vote close this question as a simple google search has it as first and second result. But if you answer, yes. Essentially your answer is a link with text that repeats what the OP has already found out himself. It adds nothing to this "thread".

Comment: funny...it's "Good Friday" ...yet cat-fights abound all over the place today!

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I would argue that my answer is not the same as what OP has found. It provided a thorough answer to OP's question.